# Preserve ampersand sign in URL from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, server, get

I have this final rule in .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Then I enter the url:

```
domain.com/docs/getting-started/installation-%26-config
```

When I use `$_GET` variable, this is the result I expect:

```
Array(
    [query] => docs/getting-started/installation-&-config
)
```

However, this is the result I get

```
Array(
    [query] => docs/getting-started/installation-
    [-config] => 
)
```

Is it possible to encode the query from .htaccess? If not, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?query=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
> ```

You need to include the `B` flag to re-encode the captured backreference, since the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against is URL-decoded. For example:

```
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?query=$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

(The `NC` flag is not required here. Neither are the *start* and *end-of-string* anchors on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.)

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b